# Java Image not immediately loading as resource

Tags: java, image, resources, loading

```
public class Resources
{
  private static Resources myResource = new Resources();

  public static Image getImage(String name)
  {
    URL url = myResource.getClass().getResource(name);
    //URL url = Resources.class.getResource(name);
    return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url);
  }
}
```

I have a resources class that looks like this where I'm putting an image file.

In my main jpanel (drawing board) I have this

```
private Image image = Resources.getImage("image.png");
```

in my paint component i have

```
g2.drawImage(image, x, y, width, height, null);
```

my problem is when i first create a box (rectangle) in which the image is supposed to draw itself to the right hand side for user to know that it is movable (like a cup handle), the image does not pop up right away, but when i click where it's supposed to be, then it shows up. I'm wondering if this has to do with the classloading or something?

****UPDATE***
Is this what is meant by SSCCE LMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;


public class ShowImage {
  static public void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Display image");
    JPanel panel = new testImage();
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    //frame.pack();

    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done setting size");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setExtendedState(frame.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

  }
}

class testImage extends JPanel {

  Image image = Resources.getImage("pin.png");

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 40, 40, null);
  }
}

class Resources
{
  private static Resources myResource = new Resources();

  // NOTE: there is no error checking here so if parameter is mistyped
  // somewhere else in code, then this will probably throw a nullpointerexception
  public static Image getImage(String name)
  {
    // TODO: Find out which way is better or preferred
    URL url = myResource.getClass().getResource(name);

    return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url);

  }
}
```

Comment: I suspect your problem is located somewhere else in your code, perhaps how you're adding components, whether revalidating containers,... You may wish to post more code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the Image in an ImageIcon, which you can put f.e. in a JLabel. This will handle the loading for you.

If this is not what you want, google for MediaTracker.

Comment: Some random points.  1) Toolkit.getImage() loads images asynchronously.  2) The OP's drawImage() method call should use the component as the ImageObserver rather 'null'.  3) One other way to get the entire image is to use ImageIO.read() method, which blocks until done.

Comment: I don't understand what f.e. is supposed to be an acronym for..?

Answer (score 1):

> the image does not pop up right away, but when i click where it's supposed to be, then it shows up

Sounds like you are doing:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel( new ImageIcon(...) );
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible( true );
frame.add( label );
```

The basic code should be:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel( new ImageIcon(...) );
frame.add( label );
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible( true );
```

If you need more help then post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.